# Decrypting a Caesar Cypher password in Python

Tags: python, encryption, key, caesar-cipher

I'm taking a programming class using Python, and for our final project we're looking to encrypt and decrypt a password. We start with a password list:

```
 #The password list - We start with it populated for testing purposes
 passwords = [["yahoo","XqffoZeo"],["google","CoIushujSetu"]]
```

Then we have our encryption key:

```
 #The encryption key for the caesar cypher
 encryptionKey=16
```

And the code which asks to look up the password:

```
 if(choice == '2'): #Lookup at password
    print("Which website do you want to lookup the password for?")
    for keyvalue in passwords:
        print(keyvalue[0])
    passwordToLookup = input()
    for key, value in passwords:
        if key == passwordToLookup:
            print(value)
```

What I need is for the print(value) to print the opposite of the key, so that the password is decrypted when it prints out. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: If you want to do arithmetic with characters, look at the built-in functions [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) and its inverse [chr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr). You could also look at [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) but that might be a bit more involved than you'd like.

Comment: There are many questions with the tag `caesar-cipher`. Have you done any research?

Comment: This is an assignment, not a question.

Comment: Yes, I spend about four hours on it yesterday, and about 90 minutes looking for the answer on here.

Answer (score 0):

Caesar-cipher replaces each letter in the alphabet by a fixed number of position. Thus, if encryptionKey is 16, then letter a --> q and z --> p.

```
def encrypt(text):
    result = ""
    encryptionKey = 16
    for i in range(len(text)):
        char = text[i]
        if (char.isupper()):  #check if upper case
            result += chr((ord(char) + encryptionKey-65)%26 + 65)
        else:
            result += chr((ord(char) + encryptionKey-97)%26 + 97)
    return result

text = "XqffoZeo"
print ("Text : "+ text) 
print ("Encrypted : " + encrypt(text))
```

then your output will be:

```
Output:
Text : XqffoZeo
Encrypted : NgvvePue
```

Comment: Thank you.  When I try to run this code though, I get this error.

  File "C:/Users/kyuss/PycharmProjects/practice4/main.py", line 16
    Output:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: what is line 16? make sure the number of spaces or tabs are correct.  I dont' have syntax error and it works for me.